# Why is this malfunctioning?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have this program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct sl{
  int32_t length;
  int32_t* arr;
} Selector;

void somefunction(Selector* temp){
  temp->length = 10;
  temp->arr = (int32_t*)malloc(temp->length * sizeof(int32_t));

  for(int i=0; i<temp->length; i++){
    temp->arr[i] = i*i;
  }
}

int main () {
  Selector* sel;

  // Make changes to struct from other function
  somefunction(sel);

  // Print each element
  for(int i=0; i<sel->length; i++){
    printf("Content of index %d: %d\n",i,sel->arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return(0);
}
```

I run it in PowerShell with: `gcc .\stest.c; .\a.exe`, and it works fine:

```
Content of index 0: 0
Content of index 1: 1
Content of index 2: 4
Content of index 3: 9
Content of index 4: 16
Content of index 5: 25
Content of index 6: 36
Content of index 7: 49
Content of index 8: 64
Content of index 9: 81
```

But if I change `int main()` to this:

```
int main () {
  Selector* sel;

  // Make changes to struct from other function
  somefunction(sel);

  // Print each element
  for(int i=0; i<sel->length; i++){
    printf("Content of index %d: %d\n",i,sel->arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // ============= ADDED CODE BELOW ============= //
  // Change each element a bit
  for(int i=0; i<sel->length; i++){
    sel->arr[i] = sel->arr[i] + 10;
  }

  // Print each element again
  for(int i=0; i<sel->length; i++){
    printf("Content of index %d after change: %d\n",i,sel->arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  // ============= ADDED CODE ABOVE ============= //
  return(0);
}
```

Suddenly it just gets a segmentation fault? Why? I didn't use the stack and overload it, I used malloc for the small arrays, it's not passing around references again like into the function to make memory go missing or something. Why doesn't this work? And how am I supposed to do it otherwise?

Comment: `Selector* sel;` defines the pointer variable `sel`. But you don't make it point anywhere. So any dereference of that pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*. What is the reason you define `sel` as a pointer? You can define it as a non-pointer, and pass a pointer to `someFunction` by using the pointer-to operator `&` (as in `Selector sel; someFunction(&sel);`)

Comment: I plan to make more functions, but I don't want the arguments to be copied (since a lot more data will be used, so I want to reduce memory and time taken for that), so I figure it would just use the originals and avoid copying if I send in pointers instead.

Comment: Does it always have to point to something from the beginning? I started off in C++, so strings kind of confused me about all of this, because I've tested and read that they turn into immutable string literals as soon as you point them somewhere. So I figured I'd have to avoid setting them from the start, I thought it would work (it looked like it at first).

Comment: That is not what you are doing. You don't have an "original". You only have a pointer that does not point to any defined address. What you want would be `Selector sel; somefunction(&sel);` as mentioned in first comment.

Comment: "I've tested and read that they turn into immutable string literals as soon as you point them somewhere" That does not make any sense. A string literal is always immutable. If you assign the address of a string literal to a `char*` you cannot change it via that pointer. If you assign the address of some other variable to the very same pointer, it does not need to be immutable.

Comment: A pointer does exactly what it name implies: It points to something elsewhere. It's not an "object" in itself in that way, it can only point to other "objects". A pointer which doesn't point anywhere can't be used.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I'll try that, thanks! :) So is it a good rule of thumb for me to think: "always use non-pointers inside of a function, but always use pointers and reference to send arguments from one function into the other"? (are pointers only useful for parameter lists?)

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, @Someprogrammerdude, but a pointer (variable) absolutely ***is*** an object itself.  This is essential to understand clearly.  It is also essential to understand that a pointer object is distinct from and independent of the object, if any, to which its value points, and that creation of a pointer does not automatically create an object for it to point to.

Comment: That rule is too generic

Comment: A great way to visualize pointers is to use pencil and paper: Draw a box on a piece of paper, label it `sel`, then draw an arrow (anywhere, it doesn't matter where). That's the pointer you have, and it just doesn't point anywhere. Now take a new piece of paper, and draw *two* boxes, Label one `sel` and the other `&sel`, and draw an arrow from `&sel` to `sel`. That's what you have with `Selector sel;` and `&sel`, where `&sel` is pointing to the `sel` object.

Comment: Yes, I imagine them as hooks which hold something. And so I imagine also that I can unhook the hook, and then rehook it to something else later (by dereferencing with * and referencing with &). In C++ when you pass an argument to a function, if it's not declared with the luxurious & in the parameter list, the function makes a copy of the object for local use. I guess that's what confused me in C. I just need some good rules-of-thumb going forward (programming for performance), but I think I can figure it out with the explanation you guys gave. Thanks once again, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to the guys in the comments who gave the solution.

The problem was caused by undefined behavior, because the pointer was not set to anything.

```
  int main() {

  Selector sel;

  // Make changes to struct from other function
  somefunction(&sel);

  // Print each element
  for(int i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
    printf("Content of index %d: %d\n",i,sel.arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // ============= ADDED CODE BELOW ============= //
  // Change each element a bit
  for(int i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
    sel.arr[i] = sel.arr[i] + 10;
  }

  // Print each element again
  for(int i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
    printf("Content of index %d after change: %d\n",i,sel.arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  // ============= ADDED CODE ABOVE ============= //
  return(0);
}
```

To summarize it, for posterity and others running into the same problem:

- Don't make "sel" a pointer.
- Send "sel" as a reference.
- Change member-variable access accordingly.